# How to run Z3 in Java from SMT-Lib standard?

Tags: java, z3

Up to now, I can run Z3 to get solution of equations in cmd on Window:

```
z3 -smt2 path_smt_lib_file
```

But how I can run Z3 with SMT-Lib standard input in Java. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find all you need in [`JavaExample.java`](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/java/JavaExample.java) in the folder `examples/java`.

Check out the [API](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacecom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3.html). In particular, if you want to read an SMT2 file, see [`Context.parseSMTLIB2File()`](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classcom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3_1_1_context.html#acbc01dc71f3fc5379b02c57bfb517be2).