# How can I use z3 in SMT-LIB format in java/eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, z3, smt

Well, I can run z3 solver in eclipse with Java binding, and the using language is Java, but I need to use the SMT-LIB format to run z3 solver in eclipse, how can I make it ?

I have research for something such as jSMTLIB Project, I don't know if it works. 
And this web [How to run Z3 in Java from SMT-Lib standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568447/how-to-run-z3-in-java-from-smt-lib-standard), it seems similar but not the point.

Answer (score 1):

SMTLib is a text-based format that z3 (and other SMT solvers) understand. It really doesn't make sense to ask "How to use Eclipse and use SMT-Lib format." It's just an ASCII text file.

You can get a better answer if you describe what you are trying to achieve; sounds like you might be having the classic XY problem, see here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem